# How to create TS files from pictures and videos?

Tags: video, dvd

I have many videos and pictures. I'd like to burn DVD with pictures and videos and play in DVD Player.
And I want to make cml tool to prepare pictures and videos for creating DVD. I know how I burn dvd from video_ts folder, but not how I create video_ts folder with pictures and videos.

1.Can I write pictures and videos to Video-DVD?
2. How to create video_ts files with pictures and videos?
3. To prepare pictures and videos for writing dvd, how should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the free [DVDStyler](http://www.dvdstyler.org/) to create DVDs.

It should also be possible to include photo slideshows, although I didn't test that.

Comment: Is there no way to make TS files in command line?

Comment: DVDStyler uses ffmpeg under the hood and even displays the ffmpeg commands it generates. You could create a sample project and copy those commands into your batch file. But there is one reason why I switched from command line ffmpeg to DVDStyler: with ffmpeg I spent hours finding the best quality/file size setting, but with DVDStyler it's calculated for you.